# how to save screenshots via webdriver on hub

Tags: java, selenium

I have several machines. One where I load my Selenium tests, read run Main.java, and several remote nodes where these autotests make.

Ok, so I have such code:

```
public static void captureScreenshot() throws InterruptedException, IOException {
     String file = DateManager.getCurrentTimestamp() + ".png";
     System.out.println(file);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(Init.webdriver);
    File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    System.out.println(srcFile);
    File destDir = new File(Init.screenshotPrefix + Init.screenshotFolder);   
    destDir.mkdir();
    FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile, new File(Init.screenshotPrefix + Init.screenshotFolder + "/" + file));
```

So, now the problem. Directory and screenshots saved not on remote hub where tests were ran, but copy to the first node where I ran Main.java. How do that screenshots saved on those machine where it were ran?